# PHP array custom looping

Tags: php, arrays

i want to create a custom toc(table of contents) that will be generated from array. for example the array values looks like this :

```
$angka = array(1,11,12,13,2,21,22,23);
```

when the values containts more than 1 digit (11,12,13,21,22,23, etc) it should be categorized as a "sub". otherwise, it should be categorized as a "non-sub". the desired output should be like this https://jsfiddle.net/thekucays/azordcv5/2/

in order to achieve that, i loop the array, check the current index, previous index, and also next index length. the code looks like this

```
<?php
$angka = array(1,11,12,13,2,21,22,23);
$hitung = count($angka);    
$keys = array_keys($angka);

echo "<ul>";
foreach(array_keys($keys) as $k){
    if(strlen($angka[$keys[$k]])==1){
        echo "<li>ini bukan sub</li>";  
    }
    else if(strlen($angka[$keys[$k]])>1 && strlen($angka[$keys[$k-1]])==1){ //buka sub baru
        echo "<li><ul>";
        echo "<li>ini buka sub</li>";
    }
    else if(strlen($angka[$keys[$k]])>1 && strlen($angka[$keys[$k-1]])>1 && strlen($angka[$keys[$k+1]])>1){  //ini masih di dalem sub
        echo "<li>ini sub tengah</li>";
    }
    else if(strlen($angka[$keys[$k]])>1 && strlen($angka[$keys[$k-1]])>1 && ($k<=$hitung || strlen($angka[$keys[$k+1]])==1)){  //akhir sub, tutup
        echo "<li>ini sub akhir</li>";
        echo "</ul></li>";
    }
}
echo "</ul>";
```

?>

the problem is, in the example code, the foreach loop will continue to loop until the array length +1 (which is 8), and will show the "Undefined offset" notice. how could i prevent that?

Comment: When you're doing `array_keys` of `$ankga` you're actually getting `0, 1..6, 7`. You're looking for `array_values`.

Comment: The `$angka[$keys[$k+1]]` is very convoluted as you could have just done `foreach($angka as $k=>$v)` but what you need is to check `isset($angka[$keys[$k+1]])` before trying to use it.

Comment: @AbraCadaver i tried to use isset, but it still showing the same notice..this is very confusing for me because isset works on my other very very simple case :(

Answer (score 0):

Hi assuming that your array will always have the same pattern (After main sub, there is a next three subs)
you can simplify your code like this

```
 <?php
    $angka = array(1,11,12,13,2,21,22,23);

    echo "<ul>";
    $counter = 0;
    foreach($angka as $value){
        $quotient = $value / 10;

        if ($quotient == 0) { // Meaning not - sub
            echo "<li>ini bukan sub</li>";  
            $counter = 0; // reset sub - index
        }
        else { // Display subs
            switch ($counter) { //Select what sub type to be displayed
                case 0: // first sub
                    echo "<li><ul>";
                    echo "<li>ini buka sub</li>";   
                    break;
                case 1: //second sub
                    echo "<li>ini sub tengah</li>";
                case 2: //third sub
                    echo "<li>ini sub akhir</li>";
                    echo "</ul></li>";
            }
            $counter++;
        }
    }
echo "</ul>";
```

In this case, you can get rid of indexing issues you encountered now.

Comment: unfortunately not, the pattern is not always like that, so is there another option? :)